# Cant seem to fix this error in vscode : "(" was not closed

Tags: python, plotly-dash, pylance

I have been trying to make visualizations using plotly dash and wanted to try out the first app example from the sites documentaion. I copied and pasted most of the code and made sure to make the correct indentations but seem to keep getting an error on the brackets. Any advice?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
    
    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name':
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name':
            ],

            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: you don't have values for the `"name"` keys, the last line should be indented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have commented on the places where the brackets are not closed. Also, you are missing the values for `"name"`. I have commented on it as well. `P` refers to parentheses `()`, `C` refers to curly brackets `{}` and `S` refers to square brackets `[]`.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[          #P1 open, S1 open
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),       # P2 open, P2 closed      
    
    html.Div(children='''                   
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''), # P3 open, P3 closed

    dcc.Graph(                                  #P4 open
        id='example-graph',         
        figure={                                #C1 open
            'data': [                           # S2 open
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name':# You are missing name parameter here;  Also C2 open; You are not closing this curly braces
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name':# You are missing name parameter here; Also C3 open; You are not closing this curly braces
            ], #S2 closed

            'layout': {                           #C4 open
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }                                     # C4 closed
        } # C1 closed
    ) # P4 closed
])#S1 closed, P1 closed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True) # this need to be indented
```

Comment: so, in summary, over 50% of the lines of code contained an error of some kind...

Comment: @D.L not 50% of the code but 3-4 lines were having errors